# AWS Aurora / Lambda serverless production environment exhibiting occasional spikes

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-aurora-serverless

We've been running our production web app off AWS Lambda / API Gateway, with an Aurora serverless database. Things had been running smoothly for over a year, but recently (coinciding with much increased periods of peak usage) we've experienced temporary slowness, and in the worst case unavailability, due to some kind of bottleneck that results in a spike in the number of DB connections and 4XX and 5XX from our two APIs.

We're using the **serverless-mysql** library to execute queries and manage DB connections.

Some potential causes of the issue that have been eliminated:

- There are no long-running queries locking up tables or anything of that sort (as demonstrated by `show full processlist` in MySQL), in fact no query runs longer than 1s accordingly to our `slow_log`
- All calls to `await serverlessMysql.query()` are immediately followed by `await serverlessMysql.end()`
- Our database manager class is instantiated outside the Lambda handler, so it isn't reinstantiated every time a Lambda instance is reused
- We've adjusted the config options for serverless-mysql so that retries aren't so aggresive. The default config makes it very aggressive in retrying to connect, both in frequency and number of retries. This has definitely helped, but has not eliminated the problem.

What details can I post that might help someone diagnose this problem? It's a major pain in the ass.

Comment: Additional information requests from your serverless-production instance. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see the load this application is getting. Which I know is easier said than done with Lambda.

You sort of hinted at it, but it's possible you're hitting the Max Connections() on the 'capacity class' your aurora serverless instance is set to. I've hit this a few times. It's hard to discover with lambda and serverless aurora because you don't have the same logging you would traditionally have.

Outside of that, the core issue you're experiencing seems to be related to spikes created from your application - so you need to discover if a query is maybe just inefficient, and running too many times at once. These are almost impossible to troubleshoot with Lambda logs. But db locks still occur with aurora serverless.

To help track down the issue, you could try the following:

- Setup APM

I highly, highly, recommend getting something like NewRelic setup and monitoring your Lambda function.

I'm pretty sure NR has a free trial option, and tracking down a problem like this would be seemingly simple with an APM. I can't tell you how much easier problems like this are to solve with a solid apm.

- Monitor traffic ingress

Again, I'm not sure of what this application is doing, but it could be possible that a spike in network traffic from a particular user kicks off a load of queries that make things go awry. Setup a free Cloudflare account or some other proxy if you can, and determine network traffic more easily.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I'll check these out and post how it goes.

I do know that I'm not hitting the max connections on the capacity class. Or rather, not normally. When a 'spike' occurs, the number of connections quickly leaps up to that maximum. It appears to be a result rather than a cause of the issue.